# mysql 2 counts grouped by from one table

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql and am trying to get a list of all problem types reported in each year from one table. I'd like to get:

2014 Network Cable     1

2015 Injection Failure 1

.
.

2015 Fork Lift Sensor  2

but so far all I can get is:

[image]

SQL:

```
     SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM 
    (SELECT natureOfProblem, COUNT(*) AS year2014
    FROM problem
    WHERE dateProblemStarted < '20150101'
    GROUP BY natureOfProblem) a,
    (SELECT natureOfProblem, COUNT(*) AS year2015
    FROM problem
    WHERE dateProblemStarted > '20141231'
    GROUP BY natureOfProblem)b
GROUP BY a.natureOfProblem, b.natureOfProblem;
```

[image: Table: problem]

Comment: id suggest breaking each select clause out of there and testing to see if they output what your looking for. its a little easier to take it a piece at a time, then to try and do it all in one go.

Comment: Thanks, I've built up the code so each separate one works ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT year(dateProblemStarted), natureOfProblem, count(1)
FROM problem
GROUP BY year(dateProblemStarted), natureOfProblem
```

Comment: Wow thanks AlexanderMP. That's brill and so much less code too